# How to call the image of 'multiple select' attribute to frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, template

In magento 1.9.2.4, I need to map the options of 'multiple select' attribute with the image to display at frontend.

I have created an `multiple select` attribute with options like below (item1,item2, item3):

[image]

And I have put the image inside `media/img` like below:
[image]

And finally entered my code in my my `app/design/frontend/<my_package>/<my_theme>/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

The code is:

```
<div class="feature">
    <?php
    $Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
    ->getAttribute('feature')->getFrontend()
    ->getValue($_product));

    foreach($Feature as $key => $value){
    <img src="/media/img/<?php echo $multiSelectItem ?>"></img>
    echo $value;

    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

but the image is not displayed. Instead error like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in <path to /list.phtml>` is getting displayed.
someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is mixing PHP and HTML without closing the PHP tag.

You should fix your code like this:

```
<div class="feature">
<?php
$Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
->getAttribute('feature')->getFrontend()
->getValue($_product));

foreach($Feature as $key => $value): ?>
    <img src="/media/img/<?php echo $multiSelectItem ?>"></img>
    <?php echo $value; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Images are getting displayed. but it is broken. Also the option names are also displayed beneath. I don't want the option name to get displayed below the image. Please kindly suggest a solution.